# Golang: How to sort slices by days of the week?

Tags: sorting, go

I have a slice of strings which contains the days of the week like this:

```
days := []string{"M", "Th", "W", "F", "T", "S", "Su"}
```

How do I sort them so it will output like this:

```
[M T W Th F S Su]
```

starting with Monday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a map keying days to their relative order. Then you can have a type implement `sort.Interface` interface:

```
type Days []string

// map to store weekdays' relative order
var days = map[string]int{
    "M":  1,
    "T":  2,
    "W":  3,
    "Th": 4,
    "F":  5,
    "S":  6,
    "Su": 7,
}

func (d Days) Len() int      { return len(d) }
func (d Days) Swap(i, j int) { d[i], d[j] = d[j], d[i] }
func (d Days) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return days[d[i]] < days[d[j]]
}

func main() {
    ds := Days([]string{"M", "Th", "W", "F", "T", "S", "Su"})

    sort.Sort(ds)
    fmt.Println(ds)
}
```

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/lzdfI-1BJK

If you want you can move `days` in `Less` method to avoid globals. But that would be severely inefficient since the map will be initialized for each element of `Days`.

Another implementation would be to have a pre-declared slice with the days in correct order and then use `strings.Index` in `Less`. This would perform slower but since your slice is of fixed length and very small (only 7 elements), it shouldn't be much of an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You want the [`sort.Interface`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort#Interface), which lets you use `sort.Sort`. The tricky part of this is to define the `Less` method, which needs to return true if one day should be considered to come before another day. I [chose to do this](https://play.golang.org/p/9US-12_QLy) by testing the relationship of the days to each other semantically, but you could also do this by assigning each day an `int` that represents its position in the week.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type Days []string

func (d Days) Len() int {
    return len(d)
}

func (d Days) Swap(i, j int) {
    d[i], d[j] = d[j], d[i]
}

func (d Days) Less(i, j int) bool {
    switch d[i] {
        case "M":
            return true
        case "T":
            return d[j] != "M"
        case "W":
            return d[j] != "M" && d[j] != "T"
        case "Th":
            return d[j] != "M" && d[j] != "T" && d[j] != "W"
        case "F":
            return d[j] == "S" || d[j] == "Su"
        case "S":
            return d[j] == "Su"
        default:
            return false
    }
}

func main() {
    days := []string{"M", "Th", "W", "F", "T", "S", "Su"}
    sort.Sort(Days(days))
    fmt.Println(days)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Go 1.8 (Q1 2017) and the [new `sort.go`](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/27321/14/src/sort/sort.go) implementing `sort.Slice()`, [Paddy Foran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/177467/paddy-foran)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38581454/6309) would become:

```
days := []string{"M", "Th", "W", "F", "T", "S", "Su"}
sort.Slice(days,  func(i, j int) bool { return less(days[i], days[j] })
```

`less()` being a func taking two strings (first letter of two days) and comparing them.

No need for `Swap()` or `Len()` anymore (done by reflection in the new sort implementation)

Answer (score -3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = new String[] { "M", "Th", "W", "F", "T", "S", "Su" };
        // [M T W Th F S Su]
        String[] arr1 = new String[] { "M", "T", "W", "Th", "F", "S", "Su" };

        LinkedHashSet<String> h = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i].equals(arr1[j])) {
                    h.add(arr[i]);

                } else {
                    arr[i] = arr1[j];
                    h.add(arr[i]);
                }

            }

        }

        System.out.println("arr = " + h);
    }
```

Comment: This is the wrong language. The question pertains to Golang.